# Can I use OpenId with the ASP MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, openid, membership-provider, dotnetopenauth

I have a ASP.Net 2.0 website that is currently using a custom MembershipProvider and the standard login control. I would like  to replace the login control with the one from DotNetOpenId.

I override the ValidateUser which checks the username and password, but I shouldn't need to implement this when using OpenId.

Is it possible to use OpenId and still have the membership provider available to me to so that I can still use it to access the current logged in user?

Or is it the case the there is need for the using provider model anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no inbuilt provider available. But you can always implement your own provider.

Or you can check out [this one](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenIDMembership) available in codePlex.

Answer (score 4):

One web project template found at
http://code.google.com/p/dotnet-membership-provider/
has a sample membership provider class that works with dotnetopenid, although you should probably do a review of it before using it in production... the last time I checked the source code it needed a bit of work.

Comment: Vote for a better membership provider interface that works with OpenID: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general/suggestions/486926-new-membership-provider-interface-supporting-redir

Answer (score 3):

This is the premier .NET OpenID library, by Andrew Arnott, MSFT employee: http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

Not sure about integration with Membership.